Reset password experience cloud page - same password issue
we have built a custom Experience Cloud site based on aura Build Your Own template and have custom reset password VisualForce page, as Salesforce does not allow for lightning pages for this functionality.
All is working good besides scenario when users enters the same password as they curretnly have.
Salesforce accepts the password, does not throw errors, transaction ends successfully and tries to redirect the user but... it redirects to the same reset password page prompting for password change as it realized it was not correct.
It is frustrating as we can not catch this kind of situation as according to salesforce password change process was successful.
Do you have any suggestions how to handle this, even with custom solution, anything that would allow us to present an error to the user saying "Hey man, you entered an old password, please enter a new one"?
I know there is a field with Password Expiration date on User but it is not accessable via Apex code. I have also tried Site.isPasswordExpired() but it always returns true, even after entering and setting a brand new password.
This is our reset password code
    public PageReference changePassword() {
        Site.changePassword(this.newPassword, this.verifyNewPassword, null);
        PageReference ref = Page.ChangePasswordSuccess;
        ref.setRedirect(true);
        return ref;
    }


